# How update counter value on multiple screen in Flutter Hive

Tags: flutter, hive, flutter-dependencies, flutter-hive

I have problem in Flutter Hive(No SQL) counter project. I save a value in listTile on homepage but I try to update this value on counter page but it throw error that data cannot update. Please help me about this

HomePage Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:expenses_app/controllers/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:expenses_app/pages/addDetail.dart';

import 'counter_page.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int del = 0;
  DbHelper dbHelper = DbHelper();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDDF8DD),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('HomePage'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff017901),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<Map>(
        future: dbHelper.fetch(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Unexpected Error"),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      new BoxShadow(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 137, 137, 137),
                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                        offset: Offset(6, 6),
                      ),
                    ],
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "Press '+' to add values",
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                      reverse: true,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length + 100,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        //dbHelper.compactAll();
                        Map dataAtIndex;
                        try {
                          dataAtIndex = snapshot.data![index];
                        } catch (e) {
                          return Container(
                          );
                        }
                          return detailTile(
                            dataAtIndex['countvalue'],
                            dataAtIndex['description'],
                            index,
                          );
                      })
                ],
              );
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Loading"),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff017901),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AddDetail()))
              .whenComplete(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 32.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget detailTile(int value, String description,
      int index, ) {
    print("index $index");
    //container
    return InkWell(
      onLongPress: () async {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Are you sure?"),
                  content: Text("This record will be deleted"),
                  actions: [
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Text("Cancel")),
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Record Deleted");
                          await dbHelper.deleteOne(index);

                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage()));
                        },
                        child: Text("Ok")),
                  ],
                ));
      },
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>const CounterPage()));
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 12, 8, 12),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            boxShadow: [
              new BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 137, 137, 137),
                blurRadius: 20.0,
                offset: Offset(6, 6),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "$description",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  "+$value",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.green),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Add Counter Initializing value Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:expenses_app/controllers/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:expenses_app/pages/homepage.dart';

class AddDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddDetail({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddDetail> createState() => _AddDetailState();
}

class _AddDetailState extends State<AddDetail> {
  int? amount;
  String description = "No info";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDDF8DD),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add Counter Value'),
        backgroundColor:Color(0xff017901),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    boxShadow: [
                      new BoxShadow(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 137, 137, 137),
                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                        offset: Offset(6, 6),
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.numbers,
                    color: Colors.green, //change icon color here
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    //fillColor: Colors.grey,
                    hintText: "0",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    try {
                      amount = int.parse(val);
                    } catch (e) {}
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.grey),
                  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    boxShadow: [
                      new BoxShadow(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 137, 137, 137),
                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                        offset: Offset(6, 6),
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.description,
                    color: Colors.amber, //change icon color here
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "description",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    description = val;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Color(0xff017901),),
              onPressed: () async {
                if (amount != null && description.isNotEmpty) {
                  DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper();
                  await dbHelper.addData(
                      amount!, description,);
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                } else {
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please add all the Values");
                }
              },
              child: Text("Add")),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red[900]),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text("Are you sure?"),
                          content: Text("This Will delete all the records."),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                child: Text("Cancel")),
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                      msg: "All Data deleted");
                                  DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper();
                                  dbHelper.deleteAll();
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage()));
                                },
                                child: Text("Yes")),
                          ],
                        ));
              },
              child: Text("Delete All Data")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Counter Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

import '../controllers/db_helper.dart';

class CounterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CounterPageState createState() => _CounterPageState();
}

class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  int count = 0;
  String description = "No info";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDDF8DD),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff017901),
        title: Text('Counter Page'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions:[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: ()async{
                DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper();
                await dbHelper.addData(
                  count!, description,);},
            icon: Icon(Icons.save, color: Colors.white,),
          ),
        ]
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('$count',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red,
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
        ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            count++;
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff017901),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Database Helper Class

```
    import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class DbHelper {
  int deleteIndex = 0;
  late Box box;
  DbHelper() {
    openbox();
  }

  get countvalue => null;

  openbox() {
    box = Hive.box('money');
  }

  Future addData(int countvalue, String description,) async {
    var value = {
      'countvalue': countvalue,
      'description': description,
    };
    box.add(value);
  }

  Future<Map> fetch() {
    if (box.values.isEmpty) {
      return Future.value({});
    } else {
      return Future.value(box.toMap());
    }
  }

  deleteAll() {
    Hive.box('money').clear();
  }

  deleteOne(int index) async {
    await box.delete(index);
  }

  compactAll() async {
    await box.compact();
  }

  incDeleteIndex() {
    deleteIndex++;
    print("delete index $deleteIndex");
  }
  saveData() async {
    await box.put('countvalue', countvalue);
  }
}
```

Screens

[I want this working but it did not resolve on multiple tries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly1rt.jpg)